# how to set output type of a winforms application through msbuild scripts

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, msbuild, msbuild-task

hi i am new to ms build scripting
i have written a simple script to build my application

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FilesToCompile Include="Form1.cs" />       
    <FilesToCompile Include="Form1.Designer.cs" />
    <FilesToCompile Include="Program.cs" />
    <FilesToCompile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <FilesToCompile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs" />
    <FilesToCompile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ResourceFiles Include="Properties\Resources.resx" />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputDir>bin\debug</OutputDir>

    <OutputAssembly>$(OutputDir)\TestHelloAuto.exe</OutputAssembly>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="build MSbuild project file from scratch" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputDir)"/>
    <GenerateResource Sources="@(ResourceFiles)">
        <Output TaskParameter="OutputResources" ItemName="CompiledResources"/>
    </GenerateResource>
    <Csc Sources="@(FilesToCompile)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputAssembly)" Optimize="$(Optimize)" TargetType="exe" 
        Resources="@(CompiledResources)"/>
</Target>
```

my issue is that by default the "exe" that is created is of the output type Console application and opens a console when i run the exe.
how can i change the output type of the application through the script to "Windows application"
this happens even though i have my output type set as windows application through visual studio IDE.
any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have an IDE to change this for you, inside your `<PropertyGroup>` element you can change the output assembly type to what you expect by adding another XML node: `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`

Comment: @NissimAnand Could you accept the answer if so, please?